# Moving .bash_profile to Dropbox

Tags: command-line, bash

I'd like to move my .bash_profile to Dropbox to have my custom Terminal functions available on all my Macs. Is this possible and are there possible implications?

For example I have a command for doing a git add and commit in one go:

```
function gax() {
    git add .
    git commit -m "$1"
}
```

I've been unable to find any information about this.

Comment: I know you've already got an answer, but it's got me thinking about just softlinking to the dropbox .bash_profile. Something to think about.

Comment: @JMY1000 with my solution you can put additional stuff depending on the machine you're on - simply put the commands after the `if` statement. But You're right this could also be a symlink.

Comment: `ln -s ~/path/to/dropbox/bash_profile_file ~/.bash_profile `

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can have additional file in Dropbox folder and then on every machine inside your `.bash_profile` file put this:

```
FILE="/path/to/DropboxFolder/shared_bash_profile_file"
if [ -f $FILE ];
then
    source $FILE
fi
```

Comment: Since FILE could be used for other apps and such, you night want to name the variable something like "DROPBOX-RC"

Answer (score 5):

It is not a good idea to put the whole `.bash_profile` in Dropbox, either by tweaking the Dropbox paths or through a symlink. Different machines may require slightly different content of this file. Examples: different software versions installed requiring different configuration, different paths, different names for things such as partitions under `/dev/`.

Do this instead: put all your customized functions and aliases in a file `$HOME/Dropbox/my_functions.sh` and then include the line

```
. $HOME/Dropbox/my_functions.sh
```

in your `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 4):

I think is better idea to upload to a repository. Let me tell you how I did it.

I version the whole `~/bin` directory. My `.bash_profile` is on that directory. The `$HOME/.bash_profile` is a link to `~/bin/.bash_profile`.

My `.bash_profile` looks like this:

```
if [[ $OSTYPE == darwin* ]]; then
    . ~/bin/includes/exports-osx.sh
    . ~/bin/includes/bash-stuff-osx.sh
    . ~/bin/includes/aliases-osx.sh
    . ~/bin/includes/functions-osx.sh
elif [[ $OSTYPE == linux* ]]; then
    . ~/bin/includes/exports-linux.sh
    . ~/bin/includes/terminal-linux.sh
    . ~/bin/includes/aliases-linux.sh
    . ~/bin/includes/ssh-keys-linux.sh
    . ~/bin/includes/bash-stuff-linux.sh
fi

. ~/bin/includes/bash-stuff.sh
. ~/bin/includes/aliases.sh
. ~/bin/includes/powerline.sh
. ~/bin/includes/functions.sh
. ~/bin/includes/work-stuff.sh
```

That way I can easilly track changes.

To keep the repo update you can create a cron or LaunchAgents script that pull the changes on your `~/bin` directory once a day:

```
cd ~/bin && git pull origin $(git name-rev --name-only HEAD)
```

Comment: What advantages would this have over the simple solution that Mateusz presented?

Comment: @swelet from my point of view, two main advantages: you can easily revert changes to a point and you can keep track of every change.

Comment: @jherran Or you could put the git repo in the Dropbox folder as well. I do think though that Dropbox has some versioning itself.

Comment: @pydsigner I've had trouble with a Git repo in Dropbox. I'm guessing race conditions as Dropbox attempts to sync changes to a file that Git then attempts to reopen while it's still being used.

Comment: This solution implicitly uses a public repo for a critical system file, which can lead to security issues.  Dropbox and others are private.

Comment: @NewAlexandria you are absolutely wrong. You can use private repos.

Comment: You could, but you don't say that, and so an inexperienced person may mistakingly use a (*implicitly*, not explicitly) public repo, compromising their system.  Respect that other people need guidance to avoid some dangers.